# Xcode 4.2 wizard setting review/change

Tags: xcode4.2

In Xcode 4, after completing any of the File|New wizards (e.g. File, Project), is there a way to review and change any of the choices made?

For instance, when starting a new Cocoa application, I check "Create Document-Based Application", is there someplace/somehow I can later change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been assurance by a well-respected source it's not possible to re-visit those settings.